qcow2 with only grub2 BIOS installed not loading in public cloud, works in qemu though
I am trying to create a simple 200 M new qcow2 with just the grub2 BIOS mode installed in it. My objective is to get to the grub prompt or grub rescue prompt when i load the said qcow2 image in public cloud like OCI or AWS.
The following are my steps

Compiling GRUB2 in BIOS mode from source code

mkdir grub2
cd grub2
wget https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/grub/grub-2.06.tar.gz
tar -xvf grub-2.06.tar.gz
cd grub-2.06
./configure --target=x86_64 --with-platform=pc --disable-efiemu
make
grub-mkimage -v -O i386-pc -d ./grub-core -p(hd0,msdos1)/boot/grub -o core.img biosdisk part_msdos fat ntfs exfat part_gpt ext2
cp core.img i386-pc



After these steps i have boot.img, core.img and .mod files inside the i386-pc folder.

Create fresh qcow2 image and create partition table using gdisk

qemu-img create -f qcow2 cloud_grub2bios.img 200M
sudo qemu-nbd -c /dev/nbd4 cloud_grub2bios.img
sudo gdisk /dev/nbd4

Then I set the disk to gpt using o command, and then create 2 partitions, first is 4MiB BIOS boot partition, and second is Linux filesystem for the remaining space in the image. The gdisk p command output after the said operations is presented below. I also run the sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/nbd4p2 after i create the partitions.






Partition table scan:
  MBR: protective
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: present

Found valid GPT with protective MBR; using GPT.

Command (? for help): p
Disk /dev/nbd5: 409600 sectors, 200.0 MiB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512/512 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): 4AF5DA38-30C9-4094-949A-60663B89B865
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
Main partition table begins at sector 2 and ends at sector 33
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 409566
Partitions will be aligned on 2048-sector boundaries
Total free space is 2014 sectors (1007.0 KiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1            2048           10239   4.0 MiB     EF02  BIOS boot partition
   2           10240          409566   195.0 MiB   8300  Linux filesystem 


Install grub2 BIOS into the qcow2 image using grub-install present in the grub2.06 folder.

sudo mount /dev/nbd4p2 /mnt
sudo ./grub-install --target=i386-pc --boot-directory=/mnt/boot --directory=./grub-core/ /dev/nbd4
Once the grub-install command is run, i get the following output

Installing for i386-pc platform.
../grub/grub-2.06/grub-install: warning: cannot open directory `/usr/local/share/locale': No such file or directory.
Installation finished. No error reported.




Once the qcow2 image is ready,I convert it into raw image using qemu-img command then run the raw image using the following command

qemu-system-x86_64 -m 4096 -cpu max -drive file=cloud_grub2bios.raw,if=virtio,format=raw -display none -nographic

Here i am able to see the grub2 prompt correctly.

But i upload this qcow2 image to OCI or AWS, configure the image to run using BIOS firmware and check the serial console, then i get nothing. It is completely blank.

Note

I downloaded the Jammy Cloud Image from https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/jammy/20240912/jammy-server-cloudimg-amd64.img and uploaded it back to OCI. Then in my uploaded image, i set the firmware to only BIOS by unticking the UEFI option. I had to manually upload and do instead of using the ubuntu image already published in OCI cause by default the ubuntu published in OCI supports both BIOS and UEFI and preferred is UEFI and when i launch an instance it always comes up with UEFI firmware. The jammy cloud image i uploaded in OCI which i am forcing to run with BIOS firmware, comes up successfully in OCI.
I tried using the boot.img, core.img and .mod files from the jammy cloud image which is running in OCI while creating my qcow2. Even with this, my image didnt get to grub or grub rescue prompt, and continued to give me blank screen.
I have tried extensive googling, and using AI tools like Chatgpt, Gemini etc but didnt find any working solution. The closest I found to generating a fresh cloud image is https://github.com/mvallim/cloud-image-ubuntu-from-scratch but this is using grub2 in UEFI mode and they arent building grub2 from scratch like i am doing.

